# Htaccess URL rewrite - string after main URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page

```
http://example.com/product-detail.php?id=123
```

The am trying to convert the URL into user-friendly way like

```
http://example.com/usa/iphone-xs--123
```

the country USA will be dynamic and will change to Canada, Australia, etc not static value. 
What will be RewriteRule in .htaccess.

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: what will be RewriteRule in .htaccess

Comment: The one you write …? Please go read [ask]. We are not here to just _make_ stuff for you, just because you managed to drop off your requirement. We want to see you make an effort yourself first of all.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Tajniak Yes thanks working

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you want to apply 'usa' value to URL other than changing this parameter manually.

```
RewriteRule ^usa/iphone-xs--(.*)$ /product-detail.php?id=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ product-detail.php?cat=$1 [L]
```